# How to reconfigure lightdm?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, display-manager, kdm

Last night I installed **KDE**. But then however my **Desktop manager** changed into **KDM**. How can I go back to my default Desktop manager **lightdm**??

Answer (score 8):

use -

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

hope it helped you.